# Destructuring assignment vs using whole object - what about performance?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs3, vue-i18n

Does destructuring assignment (in my case with Vue composables) has any performance gain/tradeoff?

For example I have component that displays current language choosed in vue-i18n.

I can do this with destructuring:

```
<template>
  <span>locale: {{ locale }}</span>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
  const { locale } = useI18n()
</script>
```

Or by using whole object (function?)

```
<template>
  <span>locale: {{ i18n.locale.value }}</span>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
  const i18n = useI18n()
</script>
```

Same goes with other libraries or custom composables (like state management). In all tutorials or examples sometimes first option is used, and sometimes second. Is this just opinionated preference or actually one is better from another one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing object properties does barely take any time in JS. It barely matters if you do this once during destructuring, or multiple times in the template.

So it's just a matter of preference - and a matter of how many properties of the same object you use in the template (your example only ever uses one, but if multiple are used, having a seperate `const` for every single one kide of bloates the code unnecessarily)

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no significant performance implication of destructuring. It's really just syntactic sugar that makes code more concise and readable.

EDIT: I'm going to add the remark that you should not in general be worrying about the performance of core language features like this. Worry about which data structure is best for a particular use case, don't worry about what *syntax* performs best. If you are coding more or less competently, then performance optimization should be a fairly uncommon exercise and not your first consideration. Code for readability and maintainability and only worry about performance when you notice it's a problem or happen to know that it's critical.

Comment: TBH, I consider `user.name` and `user.email` or `cars.wheels.frontLeft.pressure` more readable than `userName`  and `email`  or `frontWheelPressureOfCar`. With hirarchical object, I personally prefer to read the full hirarchy over variable names which I first need to find and read the declaration for. (Exception: namespaces. They're rarely needed for context.)

Comment: @JohannesH, if you're writing a lot of React code like I do, then you're constantly writing things like `this.props.user.email`. That becomes tedious and verbose, so in that case I always destructure at least to the level of `user`. It's a nice capability in situations like that, and also for destructuring fields from an object passed as an argument where you'd otherwise be writing `param.field` instead of just `field`.

Comment: And you're not alone with it. I'm actually rather sure that the minority of programmers wuld agree with my statement above. All I wanted is to state that "it makes the ode more readable" is subjective and not universally true.

Comment: Yep for sure. I'd say the question is whether it's helpful/salient in a given context to be reminded by the code that `user` belongs to `this.props` (in my example). That's a judgement call.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a de-structure is just to use the relevant value instead of long dot notations.
Performance I do not think, but it is useful if you want to put a fail safe check if the value is not present.
The other way if not de-structure would be obj?.prp1?.prp2